# vim: How to insert output of shell command in-line?

Tags: vim

Suppose I want to edit a new libvirt XML file:

```
virsh dumpxml machine1 > machine2.xml
```

Then I open the file with `vim`,

```
vim machine2.xml
```

and then I want to change the UUID.  Now do this, I use

```
:r ! uuidgen
```

But the new UUID is inserted under the current line:

```
<uuid>6r123ttz-6t01-356t-1y7h-g7oe196c8u3m</uuid>
e67baf90-751b-4aea-a14b-aca1b881542b
```

How may I insert the output of the `uuidgen` command *into* the current line, so that if I have

```
<uuid></uuid>
```

(with the cursor between `><`), then, by executing `uuidgen` I get

```
<uuid>e67baf90-751b-4aea-a14b-aca1b881542b</uuid>
```

The question is: is possible to use the `:r` vim command without adding a new line?

Comment: I reformulated the question.  If you feel that I misrepresented you, then feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: This may be of use to you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/180178/insert-output-of-a-system-command-at-the-current-location-in-vim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a play around and this doesn't do exactly as you want as :r will always enter a newline. But it should do what you want for a result.

```
:.!UUID=`uuidgen` ; echo "<uuid>$UUID</uuid>"
```

It puts the stdout on the current line (not at the cursor) - the smarts are done with the command that is being invoked.

Comment: It create also a newline, is a nice workaround, so for the moment I consider as right answer

Comment: I know why - use printf instead of echo and it should be fine

Answer (score 7):

`:read` is an *Ex command*; these unfortunately always work on *complete lines*. You either have to work around that by first splitting and then later joining with the preceding and following lines, or you use a different command.

The [`:help i_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R) command can insert any register contents. There's a special *expression register* ([`:help quote=`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote%3D)) that executes any Vimscript expression and uses its result. Finally, the [`system()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) function executes an external command and returns its output.

So (in insert mode) `<C-R>=system('uuidgen')<CR>` will insert the command's output at the current position. Unfortunately, the output has a trailing newline, and that is preserved, so `</uuid>` moves to the next line. To avoid that, you can truncate the output, either via `system('uuidgen')[0:-2]` or `substitute(system('uuidgen'), '\n$', '', '')` as the expression.

For repeated inserts, the *expression history* can be used to recall the last expression (by pressing `<Up>`); for even more comfort, you can define a mapping for the whole thing.

Comment: This works great! I was wondering how I would map the following sequence to a normal mode mapping: 1. visual highlight of a current UUID. 2. 'c' to enter insert mode, and finally 3. executing the <C-R>=system .... I'm already stuck at figuring out how to to step 1. the dashes in UUIDs make the selection of one whole UUID a bit challenging (other that using 'inside double-quote' for cases where the UUID are enclosed in quotes)

Comment: @ChristophWegener As long as you don't have to deal with the two dashes / non-dashes variants, the length of a UUID should be constant, right? So `v25l` (selecting 36 characters for the dashed variant) would do the selection, assuming you're at the start. However, I would favor a plugin-based solution (e.g. using my [TextTransform plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4005)), and those typically allow selection of the target text via a regular expression (`'\%(^\|\X\)\zs\x\{8}-\?\x\{4}-\?\x\{4}-\?\x\{4}-\?\x\{12}\ze\%(\X\|$\)'`.

Answer (score 4):

```
fu! SetBang(v) range
        if a:v == 1
                normal gv
        endif
        let l:t = &shellredir
        let &shellredir = ">%s\ 2>/dev/tty"
        let @" = join(systemlist(input("\"!"))," ")
        let &shellredir = l:t
endf
nnoremap "! :cal SetBang(0)<cr>
xnoremap "! :cal SetBang(1)<cr>
```

Every time you press `"!`, the user will be prompted for a command, and the "unnamed" `"` register will be filled with it. You can then insert it as usual, with `P` in normal or visual mode, with `Ctrl-R"` in insert mode, etc.

For instance, having the text (caret showed by `|`):

```
<uuid>|</uuid>
```

and pressing `"!uuidgen<Enter>P` will insert the new uuid at the caret.

You could of course use other binding instead of `"!`.

Answer (score 1):

No but you do the following sequence.

Place cursor where you want to insert

```
<uuid>|</uuid>
```

Press `i` `<CR>` `^[` `k` `:r !uuidgen` `k` `3J` `x`

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit the XML directly without even using `vim`.

For example given `<uuid></uuid>` as part of the file you can insert or update the value:

```
echo '<uuid></uuid>' |
    xmlstarlet edit --update '//uuid' -v "$(uuidgen)"
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<uuid>79cc09da-a256-46d5-9974-9073cf9d7a9a</uuid>
```

This can allow you to template VM definitions and customise them programmatically.